# localization in codeigniter, different view on different language

Tags: codeigniter

I'm using [this approach](http://jeromejaglale.com/doc/php/codeigniter_i18n) to localize my codeigniter web app.
Now everything works fine, except that I want to remove this repetitive code, to localize I have to put inside every controller action following

```
public function history() 
    {            
        $selectedLang = $this->lang->lang();
        switch ($selectedLang)
        {
            case "en":
                $data['switchLang'] = "fr";  
                $langView = "company/historyEN";
                break;
            case "sr":
                $data['switchLang'] = "en";                                
                $langView = "company/history";
                break;
            default:
               $data['switchLang'] = "en";                       
                $langView = "company/history";
        }          

        $this->lang->load("content");
        $this->load->view($langView, $data);
    }
```

Is it possible to move this inside CI_Controller class which will be available for all controllers than? if so how?

or something else, please advise me into right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or what you can do is put this function in your Model and Autoload that model...So It can be avialable in all your controller..You just need to Call this mehhod that is only one line in all controller.

Okay here You Go..Make One Model and AutoLoad it from config/autoload.php
Then Put this code of yours into it....say your model name is **language**.

```
<?php
class Language extends CI_Model {
public function history() 
    {            
        $selectedLang = $this->lang->lang();
        switch ($selectedLang)
        {
            case "en":
                $data['switchLang'] = "fr";  
                $langView = "company/historyEN";
                break;
            case "sr":
                $data['switchLang'] = "en";                                
                $langView = "company/history";
                break;
            default:
               $data['switchLang'] = "en";                       
                $langView = "company/history";
        }          

        $this->lang->load("content");
        $this->load->view($langView, $data);
    }
}
```

Now from Your every Controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class controllername extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->language->history();
    }
```

Comment: please include code for that function inside model and call from controller to accept your answer. thanks

Comment: Edited my answer..Check it and tell me if any confusion is there

Answer (score 1):

The right way is that make your own core controller and put this function in that class. And you let all the controllers extend from that class. And you will be able to use this function in your controllers.

But i think the best way is to make your own template library and just autoload that and instead of using the CI view use your own template library.

Something like this

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Template {

    var $CI;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->CI = &get_instance();
    }

    function view($view = '', $data = array()) {

        $selectedLang = $this->CI->lang->lang();

        switch ($selectedLang) {
            case "en":
                $data['switchLang'] = "fr";
                $langView = $view . "EN";
                break;
            case "sr":
                $data['switchLang'] = "en";
                $langView = $view;
                break;
            default:
                $data['switchLang'] = "en";
                $langView = $view;
        }

        $this->CI->lang->load("content");

        return $this->CI->load->view($langView, $data);
    }

}

/* End of file template.php */
/* Location: ./system/application/libraries/template.php */
```

And in the controller you just use this line to get the view

```
$this->template->view('company/history', $data)
```